# Provider is not supported, or was incorrectly entered

Tags: security, gerrit, java, provider

I have installed gerrit server setup in localhost. And after making the successful connection the Web UI has been launched. There i have registered with my gmail id in "Sign in with a Launchpad ID" option.
Its worked earlier, but now it shows the error "Provider is not supported, or was incorrectly entered." when i try to login. I had searched a lot and found some solution regarding the security issues in the installed java in the system. I have Oracle Jdk8 not OpenJdk in my system. so should i have to switch to Open Jdk. Here is my error log messages from log file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88)
    ... 78 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue Fixed !**

As i have been using Oracle Java 8, i have installed Open Jdk 7 with the following commnad.

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

But issue resolved only when i have changed java home variable in gerrit.config file.

```
javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

Now the issues fixed for me..